# Explain how this css code works

Tags: css

This tab set works for me. But I don't understand the CSS logic and the semantics behind it. Especially how the the last CSS item (which I think!) helps to keep the last clicked tab highlighted until you click the next. Can someone please explain.

Here is the css:

```
/* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< start menu_ main >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
#tabmenu 
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#tabmenu li 
{   float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

#tabmenu a
{   display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #E28F58; /*brown*/
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;*/
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding:0 12px 0 12px; 
}

#tabmenu a:hover 
{   background: #333333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333333; 
}

#tabmenu a.active, #tabmenu a.active:hover 
{   background: #333333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333333;
}

/* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< end menu_main >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
```

Here is the HTML for index page:

```
<ul id="tabmenu">
<li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="programs_ar.html">Programs</a></li>
<li><a href="students.html">Student Work</a></li>
<li><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
<li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
<li><a href="about_activity.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#tabmenu a.active, #tabmenu a.active:hover 
{   background: #333333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333333;
}
```

The `<a>` tag can be in 1 of 3 states.

- Unvisited: which is the default state.
- Visited: changes its color if you clicked on it before.
- Active: which is the currently clicked `<a>`

That CSS rules tells the browser to change the background of any Active `<a>` inside #tabmenu.

Means the `<a>` that you're currently activating will be "highlighted".

The rule also says that if you hover over this activated `<a>`, it will have this background color.

So when you click on another `<a>`, the new clicked `<a>` will be the activated `<a>`, thus it will take that background color, and the previous `<a>` will be a Visited `<a>`, thus it won't take that color.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, each page is setting the "active" class on a single menu item, which is then matched by the following selector:

```
#tabmenu a.active
{   background: #333333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333333;
}
```

When you navigate to a new page with new markup, the old selection is "lost" and whatever element has `class="active"` now matches the selector.

Example:

```
<!-- you've marked the "home" link as active -->
<a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>

<!-- user clicks another link -->
<!-- browser navigates -->

<!-- on this page, "student work" has a class name of "active" -->
<a class="active" href="students.html">Student Work</a>

<!-- "home" is no longer selected; "student work" is -->
```

Put another way: any anchor with a class name of "active" will match the selector. There's nothing preventing several items from matching, such as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NnwMW/2/).

Comment: Thanks a lot all. Got it now, very clearly. Now that I understand it, it looks pretty simple :)